# How to format data in cells of crosstab using measures of different types

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

With regard to using crosstabs, is there a way to add any kind of formatting to the measures?

I have the data as follows.

[image]

I need to display col2, col4 as per the formatting specified for any geographical location. For example, in India, we show the date as 11/11/1986 and number as 1,00,000. Another country may show the data as 11.11.1986 and number as 1.00.000

How do I achieve this?

Also, while creating the crosstab, I do not add any calculated function to the crosstab, yet, it takes up the highest values for that combination of row group and column group. Why is this? Here is the picture of the same

[image]

And the jrxml for the same is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="crosstabmeasure" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="e47b3f7d-1e00-4702-a900-be50a229f085">
    <style name="Crosstab_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CG" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CT" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#005FB3">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <parameter name="Locale" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["en-IN"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from internatioinlization]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="col1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="col2" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="col3" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="col4" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <summary>
        <band height="211" splitType="Stretch">
            <crosstab>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="211" uuid="6c5ccb8a-50fc-4158-b2ba-88d864aa1e43"/>
                <rowGroup name="col11" width="60">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{col1}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="86c09a7f-46b5-4d2f-ba87-715f99d832a8"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col11}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="94fca0ea-1572-4d42-85d9-b06f92c73b6e"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total col11]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <columnGroup name="col41" height="20">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{col4}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="120" height="20" uuid="137ef406-6a2e-4629-9d38-4858c4a5ae2c">
                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col41}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="5c71211d-f1db-4911-8923-2bdb208ddb99"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total col41]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <measure name="col2_MEASURE1" class="java.lang.Integer">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{col2}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <measure name="col3_MEASURE1" class="java.sql.Timestamp">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{col3}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <crosstabCell width="120" height="20">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CD">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="861d0d3a-d774-4b0c-ae7d-ace315bf305c"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col2_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="60" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="163ed502-e753-444a-942d-832d84da0a5f">
                            </reportElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col3_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" columnTotalGroup="col41">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="2576b9e2-3bba-40e3-aa15-5f4f0aada549"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col2_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="a111181f-b60f-4afd-8292-9e260c1b9ce2"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col3_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="col11">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="9adf6c9c-acee-4673-8b70-a376e7d1cbb4"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col2_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="9baedeed-4770-4153-b639-afc0965e9467"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col3_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="col11" columnTotalGroup="col41">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="a2805e0a-080d-42be-ad86-a7e8e666f571"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col2_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="c485f69d-91e1-4b19-a8ab-bdbfa3cafcc6"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col3_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
            </crosstab>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: `is there a way to add any kind of formatting to the measures?` - Yes, you can set expression for measure

Comment: Hi Alex, Should I add the expression in the measure group or the detail group? There are 2 places where I can do it, one where $F{} is present and the other is $V{col2_measure1}

Comment: I think it is better to change *textFieldExpression* (`$V{col2_measure1}`)

Comment: I did this $V{col3_MEASURE1} != null ? DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, new Locale($P{Locale}.split("-")[0], $P{Locale}.split("-")[1])).format(DateUtils.addMinutes($V{col3_MEASURE1},$P{UtcOffSet})) : null .. The point is it works, but I need to convert the field datetime to text field. So my question is, if the method that I used converts it to string, how will I perform max,min etc on the datefield?

Comment: Alex, I did not understand the textfield. Which text field must I add the details? Even when I add and it gets converted to string, how will max,min work? Won't it do a max(string) instead of max(date)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to stay *measureExpression* AS IS and apply formatting for *textFieldExpression*.

The *textFieldExpression* in crosstab can operate with crosstab's parameters values.

- If the main *Main dataset* is using at *crosstab* we can use the
  crosstab's parameters in cells of crosstab.
- If the another *dataset*
  is using at *crosstab* we can this dataset's parameters in cells of
  crosstab.

### Example

#### Datasource

The *csv* datasource is using in example.

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
a,a123,10,12/02/2016
a,a123,20,30/01/2016
a,a123,44,21/01/2016
a,b456,5,28/03/2016
b,a123,15,23/03/2015
b,b456,100,13/05/2015
b,b456,200,10/09/2015
b,b456,130,09/09/2017
```

The name of data adapter for this datasource in the example below is *values.csv*. The first line from the file is skipped - it is contains the column's name.

#### Report template

*Col1* is using in *rowGroup*s, *col2* is using at *columnGroup*s.
With help of *measureExpression* the crosstab showing the *Sum* of *col3* for each group and the *Highest* date (*col4*).

The formatting will be applied for *textField*s. The parameter will be used for *Date* formatting.

In this example the *Main dataset* is using for showing data at crosstab. We need to pass the value of report's parameter to the crosstab's parameters, because we can't use report's parameters in crosstab (with rare exceptions).

```
<crosstabParameter name="dateFormat" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT")]]></parameterValueExpression>
</crosstabParameter>
```

- this is initialization of crosstab's parameter (*dateFormat*) with help of *REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP* report's parameter. The value of  *REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP* parameter can be accessed from crosstab.

The value of report's parameter *SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT* can be passed to the report for example with help of *Java* code.

The *jrxml* code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Formatted measures" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="values.csv"/>
    <style name="Crosstab_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <parameter name="SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy")]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <field name="col1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="col2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="col3" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="col4" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <summary>
        <band height="270">
            <crosstab>
                <reportElement x="20" y="70" width="525" height="200" >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                </reportElement>
                <crosstabParameter name="dateFormat" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT")]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <rowGroup name="col1" width="60">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{col1}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <columnGroup name="col2" height="20">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{col2}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="180" height="20"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <measure name="col3_MEASURE" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{col3}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <measure name="col4_MEASURE" class="java.util.Date" calculation="Highest">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{col4}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <crosstabCell width="180" height="40">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CD">
                        <textField pattern="#,##0.00">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="180" height="20"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col3_MEASURE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="180" height="20"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col2}.equals("a123") ? $P{dateFormat}.format($V{col4_MEASURE}) :
 new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy").format($V{col4_MEASURE})]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
            </crosstab>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

The expression for showing data can be complex as in this example. With help of expression:

`<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col2}.equals("a123") ? $P{dateFormat}.format($V{col4_MEASURE}) :
 new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy").format($V{col4_MEASURE})]]></textFieldExpression>`

we are showing dates in different formats for different columns (*col2*).

#### Output result

The result in *Jaspersoft Studio* will be:

[image: Preview in JSS]

The sum of *Integer* values formatted with help of *pattern* attribute and the max value of *Date* values formatted with help of *Java* expression.

Comment: That is a wonderful explanation Alex. But, I am unable to do the same. I have used parameters in the formatting expressions. Please have a look at the code in the link https://gist.github.com/RathiMittha/e8100ef8734b7b309eb2076226f7256c , I keep getting the error 'Expression ID not found for expression <<$P{Locale}>>.' The code is present in the link. Any help on this would be of great great help !!

Comment: Ok Alex, thank you. I will try this out. One more question, the date pattern is not predetermined it is based on user location. So for India the locale is 'en-IN', for germany 'de-DE' , for finnish its 'fi-FI' and the date pattern changes accordingly, for India it is 11/11/1986 , for germany its 1986/11/11, for finnish its 11.11.1986. So, the format changes dynamically, how do I incorporate this? Thanks in advance